# Have float:right span contractible

Tags: html, css

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maNjj/) for my situation. Essentially, I have a floating `span` which is obstructive when the window is made small (it goes on another line).

When the window is small, I want the floating span to shrink with the text that doesn't fit hidden (some sort of `overflow: hidden`, I guess). Essentially, I want to give priority to the text on the left, and have the floating `span` gradually go away as the window is made small.

Comment: So all the text should be on one line, and the text on the right should gradually be cut off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XMX9y/

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    border: 1px dashed #444;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: right;
}
/* first span */
.row span:first-child {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
/* second span */
.row span + span {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="row">
    <span>left left left left left left</span>
    <span>What is the best way to</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Genius. Works great on Chrome.

Comment: If you don't need to support older browsers, you can change `.row span + span` into `.row span:last-child`, which is clearer.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/XMX9y/3/. The order of the `span`s had to be swapped.

Comment: Yes! Well, Webkit preferably.